# Don't know why my Kivy Dropdown list isn't showing

Tags: python, kivy

For some reason my kivy dropdown list is not showing and im following the exact method from the documentation. Still no avail. ill appreciate any help. Here is my code.

```
class NewProjectScreen(Screen):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewProjectScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.location = TextInput(multiline = True, pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}, hint_text = "Location", size_hint = [0.4, 0.10], font_name = 'fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf', id = "location")
        self.add_widget(self.location)
        self.location.bind(text = self.dropdown)


    def dropdown(self, instance, value):
        if len(self.location.text) > 0:
            towns_cities = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=' + self.location.text + "&inputtype=textquery&fields&types=geocode&sensor=false&types=regions&key=" + API_KEY
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(towns_cities).read()
            directions = json.loads(response)
            print(directions)
            for places in directions:
                place = places
            self.dropdown = DropDown()
            for index in range (5):
                btn = Button(text = places[index])
                self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.open(btn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems with your code.

- Your code `self.dropdown = DropDown()` redefines `self.dropdown`, which is a method of your `NewProjectScreen` class. I suggest refactoring to change the name of that method.
- Your code `self.dropdown.open(btn)` tries to attach the `DropDown` to one of its own buttons (probably won't work). I suggest replacing that with `self.dropdown.open(self.location)`.
- As mentioned in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html) "When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually". I suggest modifying your `Button` creation to `btn = Button(text = places[index], size_hint=(1, None), height=50)`.

I believe the above changes will get your code working.